# How to create a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0, \infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I don't understand how to do this. The tip I have for the question is to first find a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f : (0,1) \to (0,\infty) , \, x \mapsto -\ln(1 - x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a continuous one: $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}-1$

Answer (score 2):

Consider first the bijection $f\colon x\mapsto \frac 1 {1-x}\colon (0,1) \to (1,+\infty)$, which is continuous and order-preserving.

Now $f-1$ is the bijection you want:
$$
x\mapsto \frac x {1-x}\colon (0,1) \to (0,+\infty)
$$
It too is continuous and order-preserving.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle f(x) = \tan   (x{\pi/2})$